# Can't set image to CircularImageView

Tags: android, imageview, firebase-authentication, google-signin

In my app, I used Navigation drawer. In the header of my Navigation drawer, I set an CircularImageView and etc.

So when the user logged in, the app should fetch the photo Uri using GoogleSignInAccounts object, then using InputStream and Drawable objects, i set a drawable image to that CircularImageView.

But the CircularImageView is still empty and the following part is not working. The part is:

```
    GoogleSignInAccount account = GoogleSignIn.getLastSignedInAccount(getApplicationContext());


    View head = navigationView.getHeaderView(0);
    TextView textView = (TextView) head.findViewById(R.id.people);
    TextView textView1 = (TextView) head.findViewById(R.id.email);
    CircleImageView circleImageView = (CircleImageView) head.findViewById(R.id.pp);


    Menu nav_Menu = navigationView.getMenu();
    nav_Menu.findItem(R.id.logout).setVisible(false);

    if (account != null) {
        nav_Menu.findItem(R.id.logout).setVisible(true);

        textView.setText(account.getDisplayName());
        textView1.setText(account.getEmail());

        Uri myuri = account.getPhotoUrl();
        try {
            InputStream inputStream = getContentResolver().openInputStream(myuri);
            Drawable drawable = Drawable.createFromStream(inputStream, null);
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), ""+drawable, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            circleImageView.setImageDrawable(drawable);
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    } else if(account == null){
        textView.setText("");
        textView1.setText("");
        circleImageView.setImageURI(null);
    }
```

Can anyone suggest what am i doing wrong? 
Any advice/help would be appreciated. :)

Comment: Is there any exception ?

Comment: No, no exceptions in the stack trace

Comment: [Off] Why don't you use `Glide / Picasso` to load the photo?

Comment: Use a image loader to load images efficiently . just Single line of code .

Comment: Which loader would be efficient?

Comment: Picasso had done the work for me, thanks mates <3

Comment: It depends on what you want to do. They both have pro and cons. See here
https://androidcreativity.wordpress.com/2017/04/22/compare-image-library/